# old swift code is not working (animating a UIView)

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview

i have found this code which is responsible for animating a UIView but unfortunately the code does not work and i can not figure the reason (maybe an older version of swift)

this is the code :

(this is helper function according to the creator)

```
func moveView(#view:UIView, toPoint destination:CGPoint, completion☹()->())?) {
 //Always animate on main thread
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () Void in 
   //Use UIView animation API
   UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping:    
    0.6, initialSpringVelocity: 0.3, options:          
    UIViewAnimationOptions.AllowAnimatedContent, animations: { () -> 
    Void in 
           //do actual move
           view.center = destination
    }, completion: { (complete) -> Void in
           //when animation completes, activate block if not nil
           if complete {
              if let c = completion {
                 c()
              }
           }
    })
 })
}
```

and this is the animation

```
//Create your face object (Just a UIImageView with a face as the image
var face = Face();
face.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50)
//find our trajectory points
var center = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2, self.view.frame.size.height/2);
var left = CGPointMake(center.x *-0.3, center.y)
var right = CGPointMake(center.x *2.2, center.y)
//place our view off screen
face.center = right
self.view.addSubview(face)
//move to center
moveView(view: face, toPoint: center) { () -> () in
  //Do your Pop
  face.pop()
  // Move to left
  moveView(view: face, toPoint: left, completion: { () -> () in
  }
}
```

and i quote from the creator of the code

> General Steps: Create a new face on the right edge of the screen. Make
>   the face visible. Move the face to the middle of the screen. Pop the
>   face Start the process with the next face. Move the first face to the
>   left as soon as the new face gets to the middle.
>
> Actual slide animation Once again, we will do the following here: Move
>   view off screen on the right Move to center Pop Move to left
>
> To get the repeating effect, just call this method on a timer

and a summary :

> UIView’s animation API is very powerful. Both the pop and movement
>   animations use depend on this API. If you’re stuck with trying to
>   create an animation, UIView animation block is usually a good place to
>   start.

NOTE : im a beginner in IOS development if anyone can please explain the code for me

Comment: all is well. Thank you sir, i appreciate your help really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed this `moveView` method had a few issues, one being it was written for Swift 1 (but there were also some typos, faulty characters and useless operations).

Here's the fixed version:

```
func moveView(view view:UIView, toPoint destination: CGPoint, afterAnim: ()->()) {
 //Always animate on main thread
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
   //Use UIView animation API
   UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping:
    0.6, initialSpringVelocity: 0.3, options:
    UIViewAnimationOptions.AllowAnimatedContent, animations: { () -> Void in
           //do actual move
           view.center = destination
    }, completion: { (complete) -> Void in
           //if and when animation completes, callback
           if complete {
              afterAnim()
           }
    })
 })
}
```

You can use it like this now:

```
moveView(view: face, toPoint: center) {
    //Do your Pop
    face.pop()
    // Move to left
    moveView(view: face, toPoint: left) {
        // Do stuff when the move is finished
    }
}
```

Observe the differences between your version and mine to understand what was obsolete/wrong and how I fixed it. I'll help if you're stuck.